# PHP Script stops executing with many objects

Tags: php, list, oop

i got a script which creates a list implementation of messages being sent between users.
Everything works fine, till the amount of messages rises up to about 77.000.

For every message a object will be created and every object has a reference to the next message object.

I enabled error reporting and increased the memory limit - I don't get any errors and the http status code is a 200 Ok, even if the developer console tells me that the request failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have verified that it is not a memory limit issue, this could be a limitation of PHP....similar to this question:

[How to Avoid PHP Object Nesting/Creation Limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581952/how-to-avoid-php-object-nesting-creation-limit)

Comment: well...great :( 
is it maybe possible to remove those limitations?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with 77 000 objects in the same PHP script - it is something wrong with the architecture, php is not right choice for such calculations (even if it can handle this under some circumstances)

to track this particular error try to set in php.ini:

```
display_errors=1
display_startup_errors=1
error_reporting=-1
log_errors=1
memory_limit=to any reasonable value
max_input_time=to any reasonable value
max_execution_time=to any reasonable value
report_memleaks=1
error_log=writable path
```

consider using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) extension

don't forget to restart apache after changing proper php.ini (you can have different php.ini for apache and cli)

check if any set_error_handler or set_exception_handler functions are called in your code

Comment: the architecture is alright - the programmer got some problems :)
no, this is just a application for my personal use, it will never be in production of anything; in a real application I wouldn't do things like that :D

This php.ini settings do not help. 
well, no problem because I can just rewrite the application in java :)