# PHP PDO fetch() loop dies after processing part of large dataset

Tags: php, mysql, loops, memory, pdo

I have a PHP script which processes a "large" dataset (about 100K records) from a PDO query into a single collection of objects, in a typical loop:

```
while ($record = $query->fetch()) {
    $obj = new Thing($record);

    /* do some processing */

    $list[] = $obj;
    $count++;
}

error_log('Processed '.$count.' records');
```

This loop processes about 50% of the dataset and then inexplicably breaks.

Things I have tried:

- Memory profiling: `memory_get_peak_usage()` consistently outputs about 63MB before the loop dies. The memory limit is 512MB, set through php.ini.
- Using `set_time_limit()` to increase script execution time to 1 hour (3600 seconds). The loop breaks long before that and I don't see the usual error in the log for this one.
- Setting `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` to `false` to avoid buffering the entire dataset
- Logging out `$query->errorInfo()` immediately after the loop break. This was no help as the error code was "00000".
- Checking the MySQL error log. Nothing of note in there before, after, or while this script runs.
- Batching the processing into 20K-record chunks. No difference. Loop broke in the same spot. However, by "cleaning up" the PDO statement object at the end of each batch, I was able to get the processed total to 54%.

Other weird behavior:

- When I set the memory limit using `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024MB')`, the loop actually dies *earlier* than with a smaller memory limit, at about 20% progress.
- During this loop, the PHP process uses 100% CPU, but once it breaks, usage drops back down to 2%, despite immediate processing in another loop immediately afterwards. Likely, the connection with the MySQL server in the first loop is very resource-intensive.

I am doing this all locally using MAMP PRO if that makes any difference.

Is there something else that could be consistently breaking this loop that I haven't checked? Is this simply not a viable strategy for processing this many records?

### UPDATE

After using a batching strategy (20K increments), I have started to see a MySQL error consistently around the third batch: `MySQL server has gone away`; possibly a symptom of a long-running unbuffered query.

Comment: If you are running script on browser, does it returns 500 internal server error or white blank page? And also did you open errors and warnings on php.ini? Recently something similar happened to me when i was trying to import a huge dataset from an xml into mysql via php.

Comment: @ADASein, I am trying a batched approach as we speak without much success, by splitting the processing into chunks of roughly 20K records. I will update my question if I confirm this doesn't work either.

Comment: @HddnTHA, no this not an internal server error, the `$query->fetch()` fails to return a record at about the 50K iteration point, therefore the `while` loop breaks.

Comment: First make triple sure you have error reporting enabled and still no error is being logged (as it appears to be the case). If this happens then the PHP process segfaults which is a) indication of a bug and b) not something you can directly fix. Most of the time this happens due to some bug in a PHP extension, but sometimes it's also the core. Usually there are workarounds. If going down this path, I recommend taking a good hard look inside the Thing constructor for anything that's not bog-standard PHP.

Comment: Using a try..catch block not catching any exception?

Comment: @Jon, the `Thing` class is plain old PHP, nothing out of the ordinary. I have had `error_reporting(-1)` set this whole time, so hopefully nothing is getting passed that.

Comment: while i don't know what exactly causes the problem, i would try to change the `Thing` class so you don't have to create it inside the loop. creating it inside makes no sense, since you don't re-use the  instances that are being created. move the `__construct` behavior to some `public function`. then create the instance once before the loop and use your new function inside of it. maybe there is some weird problem with creating 100k instances of a `PHP` class. and there is no sense in creating 100k instances, when you just need one.

Comment: @northkildonan, I do use the `Thing` instances being created, implied by the `/* do some processing */` comment within the loop. The only restriction on creating 100K instances of something is memory and I've already ruled that out as the problem.

Comment: @Mark well, maybe there is an hidden limit for instances. i mean, we talking bout 100k instances. and it would be at least worth a try.

Comment: @Mark one simple google search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581952/how-to-avoid-php-object-nesting-creation-limit -> `"So if PHP chokes on nesting objects 40000 levels deep... don't nest objects 40000 levels deep."`

Answer (score 0):

If You really need to process 100K records on the fly, You should do the processing in SQL, and fetch the result as You need it - it should save a lot of time.

But You probably cant do that for some reason. You always process all the rows from statement, so use fetchAll once - and let MySQL alone after that, like that:

```
$records = $query->fetchAll()
foreach ($records as record) 
{
    $obj = new Thing($record);
    /* do some processing */
    $list[] = $obj;
    $count++;
}
error_log('Processed '.$count.' records');
```

Also, select only rows that You will use.
If this does not help, You can try with this: [Setting a connect timeout with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403082/setting-a-connect-timeout-with-pdo) .